# Is there any possibilities of getting "country name" using "currency code" in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to get the **country name** using **currency code** which I have.

Is there any possibility?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own module where you associate different currencies to countries. Then filter the values in your module table and get the countries associated to a specific currency. Below is link that are list out currency and country list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_capitals_with_currency_and_language

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, want country name using currency code?? If you want to get country name by using country code then

```
<?php
$country = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->loadByCode($code);
echo  $country->getName();
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what does $code stands here and how can we pass currency code to get country name ?

Comment: Here $code stands for ISO country codes e.g: "BR" for Brazil. i don't think it is possible to get country name by its code because there is no relation between country and currency in magento like that. you can get currency name by its code through this code Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency("AUD")->getName();